# Hudson cmd.exe running as

Tags: hudson, cmd

Where does hudson CI get user to run the cmd.exe ?
I'm trying to start and stop some remote services on various slaves and special credentials that are different than what hudson is using are needed. I can't find a place to override the user. I've tried running the server as various users, but it doesn't change anything.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to start and stop the services on the remote machine you need to login with these credentials on the remote machine, since I haven't found a way to start and stop a service on remote machine.

There are different ways to do that. You can create a slave that runs on the remote machines with the correct credentials. You can even create more than one slave for the same machine without any issues, than you can use different credentials for the same machine. These can then fire up the `net stop` and `net start` command.

You can also use the [SSH plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/SSH+plugin). This allows you to configure pre- and post-build ssh scripts. You 'just' need and ssh server on the windows machine. The password for the connection will be stored encrypted.

Use a commad line tool. So far I haven't found a Windows on board tool to have a scripted login to the remote machine. I would use plink for that task. plink is the scripted version of putty. Putty supports different connection types. So you can also use the build in telnet service (not recommended since telnet does not encrypt the connection). Disadvantage is that you will have the password unencrypted in the job configuration.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem, and I resorted to using PsExec. To my advantage, our machines exist on a separate LAN, within 2 firewalls, so I was OK with unencrypted passwords floating around. I had also explored SSH w/ Putty, which seemed to work, but not straightforward.

If someone can help with single line `runas` command, that could work too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how your slaves are connected to Hudson, but I'll assume it's through the "hudson slave" service, since that's probably the most popular way to connect Windows slaves.

If so, the CMD.EXE is run with the same permissions as the user running the service.  This can be checked by:
 1. run services.msc
 2. double-click hudson-slave service
 3. go to Log On tab

By default, the slave service runs as "LocalSystem", which is the most powerful account on the system.  It should be able to do whatever you need it to do.  (i.e. start/stop services)